# Sage BOI - Error 200 when invoking NewObject on AR_Customer_bus. I'm aiming to create a new customer via the BOI using C#

Tags: c#, com, idispatch

This is a Sage cloud 2019 Business Object Interface question.

I'm experiencing issues trying to new up an AR_Customer_bus object, my eventual aim is to be able to create a new customer using the BOI. The error I'm getting is a 200 error.

Full disclosure; I'm a Sage BOI novice, although I'm a fairly seasoned developer and I don't have a Sage background but I do have the Sage BOI instructional materials. I have also posted this question on the Sage forum but the activity on the forums is pretty low so I'm covering my bases:
https://www.sagecity.com/support_communities/sage100_erp/f/sage-100-business-object-interface/146142/unable-to-newobject-the-ar_customer_bus

Any assistance with this issue is greatly appreciated, it doesn't even have to be an exact solution, just general guidance that could help facilitate a solution would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code so far, also note that I've written this off the back of several examples I've found across my way:

```
/// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Instantiate a ProvidexX.Script object and initialize with the path to MAS90\Home
            using (DispatchObject pvx = new DispatchObject("ProvideX.Script"))
            {
                // Replace the text "*PATH TO MAS90\HOME*" with the correct MAS90\Home path in the line below
                pvx.InvokeMethod("Init", @"[Correct path]");

                // Instantiate a new Session object and initialize the session
                // by setting the user, company, date and module
                using (DispatchObject oSS = new DispatchObject(pvx.InvokeMethod("NewObject", "SY_Session")))
                {
                    oSS.InvokeMethod("nLogon");
                    oSS.InvokeMethod("nSetUser", new object[] {"[Username]", "[Password]"});
                    oSS.InvokeMethod("nSetCompany", "[CompanyName]");
                    oSS.InvokeMethod("nSetDate", "A/R", "05312006");
                    oSS.InvokeMethod("nSetModule", "A/R");

                    // Get the Task ID for the AR_Customer_ui program
                    int TaskID = (int) oSS.InvokeMethod("nLookupTask", "AR_Customer_ui");
                    //int TaskID = (int)oSS.InvokeMethod("nLookupTask", "AR_Invoice_ui");
                    oSS.InvokeMethod("nSetProgram", TaskID);

                    CreateCustomer(pvx, oSS, out var customerNumber);
                    GetCustomerList(pvx, oSS, out var bob);

                }
            }


        }

        private static string CreateCustomer(DispatchObject pvx, DispatchObject oSS, out string customerNumber)
        {
            customerNumber = "";


            using (DispatchObject oARCustomerEntry = new DispatchObject(pvx.InvokeMethod("NewObject", "AR_Customer_bus", oSS.GetObject()))) //Error 200 throw here.
            {
                try
                {
                    object[] nextCustomerNumber = new object[] { "CustomerNo$" };

                    //Getting Next Customer Number
                    oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nGetNextCustomerNo", nextCustomerNumber);

                    Console.WriteLine(nextCustomerNumber[0].ToString());

                    object retVal = 0;

                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetKeyValue", new object[] { "ARDivisionNo$", "01" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetKeyValue", new object[] { "CustomerNo$", nextCustomerNumber[0].ToString() });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethod("nSetKey");

                    Console.WriteLine(retVal.ToString());

                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "CustomerName$", "ROSE DAWSON" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "AddressLine1$", "1234 LONG DREAM ST" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "AddressLine2$", "" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "AddressLine3$", "" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "City$", "CITRUS HEIGHTS" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "State$", "CA" });

                    Console.WriteLine(retVal.ToString());

                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "ZipCode$", "95621" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "CountryCode$", "USA" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "SalespersonDivisionNo$", "01" });
                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethodByRef("nSetValue", new object[] { "SalespersonNo$", "RAP" });
                    Console.WriteLine(retVal.ToString());

                    retVal = oARCustomerEntry.InvokeMethod("nWrite");

                    if (retVal.ToString() == "0")
                    {
                        object errorMsg = oARCustomerEntry.GetProperty("sLastErrorMsg");
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg.ToString());
                        Console.Read();
                    }

                    customerNumber = nextCustomerNumber[0].ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine(retVal.ToString());

                    Console.Read();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    object errorMsg = oARCustomerEntry.GetProperty("sLastErrorMsg");

                    Console.WriteLine(errorMsg.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    Console.Read();
                }
                finally
                {
                    oARCustomerEntry.Dispose();
                }
            }

            return customerNumber;
        }
```

Below is the line that throws the error:

```
public object GetObject() 
    {
        return m_object;
    }
```

Then it calls InvokeMethod which is shown below, this is exactly where the error 200 is thrown:

```
public object InvokeMethod(string sMethodName, params object[] aryParams)
    {
        return m_object.GetType().InvokeMember(sMethodName, m_flgMethod, null, m_object, aryParams);
    }
```

My first thoughts were this is a permissions issue (since I had encountered that before, but the user that I'm setting has the role "Full Administrator" which when looking at the roles maintenance section of sage I can see that the role has every security permission assigned.

Please note: I have been able to new up other business objects like AR_DepositHistory_bus without a problem, and I've also managed to new up AR_Customer_ui and AR_Customer_svc so I don't know why this is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the solution that worked for me](https://www.sagecity.com/support_communities/sage100_erp/f/sage-100-business-object-interface/146142/unable-to-newobject-the-ar_customer_bus)

**Solution 1**
It took a while to get through this blocking issue but here's the resolution that worked for me:

1. I took the VB script provided by David Speck in the URL above and
   made several modifications for it to work in VB.net, I posted my full script with the modifications in the link above.
2. I ran the script and found that I was able to new up a AR_Customer_bus object without a problem.
3. Working on advice provided by David Speck in the URL again I retested my C# application again and found that it worked.

**Alternative solution**

1. I believe following the advice provided by Sage100User would've also resolved the issue. [Link here](https://www.dsdinc.com/instal-configure-sage-100-erp-sales-tax-avalara/) The article shows you how to manually register the .dll files.

**Cause**
The cause could be a couple of things:

1. Sage was running on a Windows 2012 machine (This sometimes causes issues with the BOI).
2. We use Avatax at our company which also is known to cause issues with the BOI.
3. This is most likely the ACTUAL reason why I couldn't new up the AR_Customer_bus which is that I don't believe the .dll's were registered properly on my workstation.

I really hope this helps out others that hit against this same issue, from my understanding it's a fairly common one and one that took a long time to resolve.